# Why is my if statement not being read properly?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I have a script that backs up a user profile from the local, or remote machine and places it onto a share: `$Global:Shared_BackupPath = "\\server\share\"`. I've been tweaking it a little more and just ended up making some variables into *Global* variables (not sure if this is the issue - *dont see why it would be*).

This is the condition:

```
if(-not (Get-EventSubscriber)){
```

I tried changing it to `-eq $null` to see if it would make any difference, but it didn't.

Its just not analyzing the condition properly and goes on to display my message box before all Jobs are done: it's "*supposed*" to wait till there's no more events and then display the message box:

```
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged -Action {
        #Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
            $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
            $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
            if(-not (Get-EventSubscriber)){
                $Profile_Sum = Get-ChildItem -Path $Global:BackUp_Path -Recurse |
                    Measure-Object -Property length -Sum |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
                        $Size = try{if($Profile_Sum -lt 1048576){ $TinyByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1KB) + " KB"; $TinyByte }
                        elseif($Profile_Sum -gt 1048576 -and $Profile_Sum -lt 1073741824){ $MediumByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1MB) + " MB"; $MediumByte }
                        elseif($Profile_Sum -gt 1073741824){ $GiganticByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1GB) + " GB"; $GiganticByte } } Catch {}
            
                $Begin_Time = Get-Item -Path $Global:BackUp_Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime
               
                $End_Time = Get-Date -Format G  

                Get-Job | Remove-Job 
                [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Copying Complete!`nStart Time: $Begin_Time  `nEnd Time: $End_Time `nProfile Size copied: $Size")
                       
                        }
                    } | Out-Null 
                }
```

I feel like I may have an idea due to the event itself being registered as a job but, not too sure how to go about it and have it wait until its done with **ALL** jobs before displaying the messagebox informing me when the copying is complete. Other than that, the script works just fine and anyone reading this can feel free to use it themselves. Heres the full Script:

```
Function PFL-UserBackUp{
[cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipeLine=$true,
                   ValueFromPipeLineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('CN','Computer','server','node')]
        [ValidateLength(1, 15)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME )
Begin{
    $Global:Shared_BackupPath = "\\server\share\"
    }
Process{
    Foreach($Computer in $ComputerName){
        Try{
            $PSSession  = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop 

            [array]$User_List = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 
                                    Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users" -Exclude Public, Default* | 
                                    Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending } -Session $PSSession

    $userinfo1 = foreach ($user in $User_List.name) {
      $userinfo = (net user $user /domain | Select-String "Full Name" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -replace "Full Name                    ", "" 2>&1 | Out-String -Stream
        if ($userinfo.Length -lt 4) { "NO DISPLAY NAME in ADUC" }
            elseif($LASTEXITCODE -eq 2) { "ACCOUNT NOT in ADUC" }
            elseif($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { $userinfo }
                else { "Error occured" }
                }
 
     $(for($i=0; $i -lt $User_List.Count; $i++){
        [pscustomobject]@{
                'User Display Name    '  = "$($i): $($userinfo1[$i])"
                '    NAME    '           = $User_List.name[$i]
                'Last Modified'          = "$($User_List.LastWriteTime[$i])" 
                'Profile Size '          = Try{
                                             $ProfilePath = $User_List.FullName[$i] 
                                             $Profile_Sum = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
                                                        Get-ChildItem -Path $Using:ProfilePath -Recurse |
                                                                Where-Object {$_.PSParentPath -match "Documents|Desktop|Music|Videos|Downloads|Links|Pictures|Favorites|Contacts" -and $_.DirectoryName -notmatch "OneDrive" } | 
                                                                Measure-Object -Property length -Sum |
                                                                Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum } -Session $PSSession
                                                                    if($Profile_Sum -lt 1048576){ $TinyByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1KB) + " KB"; $TinyByte }
                                                                    elseif($Profile_Sum -gt 1048576 -and $Profile_Sum -lt 1073741824){ $MediumByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1MB) + " MB"; $MediumByte }
                                                                    elseif($Profile_Sum -gt 1073741824){ $GiganticByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1GB) + " GB"; $GiganticByte } #Profile Size
                                              } Catch { "$($Error[0].Exception.Message.Split('.')[2].Trim())!" }
                                         }
                                    } ) | Out-Host

Write-Host "Press 'Q' to quit."
$ii = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Number of Profile to Back-Up"
$i  = $ii.Trim() -split ","
    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($i) -eq $true) { "Null string"; Break }
    elseif($i.ToLower() -like "q*") {"Q was selected. Stopping script."; Break }


<#    
    " "    
    "     Following Profiles will be Saved:"
    "     ------------------------------------"
        foreach($i in $index) { "$($i.trim()): $($userinfo1[$i])" }
    " "


$Confirm = Read-Host -Prompt "Are you sure you want to continue? [Y/N]"
    if($Confirm.ToLower().TrimStart() -like "n*" -or $Confirm.ToLower() -like "q*"){Break} 
    if([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Confirm.Trim()) -eq $true) { "Null string"; Break }#>


        $Profile_Path       = "C:\Users\$($User_List.name[$i])"
        $Literal_Name       = $userinfo1[$i].Replace('/','-')
        $Global:BackUp_Path = "$Global:Shared_BackupPath$Literal_Name"
        $Test_Path          = Test-Path -Path $Global:BackUp_Path 
            if($Test_Path -eq $false){
                New-Item -Path $Global:BackUp_Path -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
                Start-Process $Global:BackUp_Path}
            elseif($Test_Path -eq $true){
                $Find_OldName  = Get-ChildItem -Path "$Global:Shared_BackupPath" -Filter "$Literal_Name" -Directory |
                                     Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
                                     Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName -First 1

                 $New_PathName = $Find_OldName + "1"
                    New-Item -Path "$Global:Shared_BackupPath" -Name $New_PathName -ItemType Directory -OutVariable Global:BackUp_Path | Out-Null #Global:BackUp_Path variable declared
                    $Global:BackUp_Path = $Global:BackUp_Path.FullName
                    Start-Process $Global:BackUp_Path}


$Global:Start_Time = Get-Date -Format G


#Favorites Copy   
$FireFox_Favorites = "C:\Users\$($User_List.name[$i])\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\*.default\places.sqlite"
$Chrome_Favorites  = "C:\Users\$($User_List.name[$i])\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks"
$Chrome_Favorites2 = "C:\Users\$($User_List.name[$i])\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks.bak"
$Sticky_Notes      = "C:\Users\$($User_List.name[$i])\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\plum.sqlite"

$Favorites_Array   = @($FireFox_Favorites,$Chrome_Favorites,$Chrome_Favorites2,$Sticky_Notes)
    Foreach($File in $Favorites_Array){
        $Test_File = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Test-Path -Path $File }
            if($Test_File -eq $true){
                Copy-Item -Path $File -Destination $Global:BackUp_Path -Force -Recurse -FromSession $PSSession 
                        }
                    }                     

#Folders Copy
$Folders = @('Desktop','Documents','Favorites','Links','Downloads','Music','Videos','Pictures','Contacts') 
    Foreach($Folder in $Folders){
        #Create Arugments for seperate thread
        $ArgumentsArray = $null

        $ArgumentsArray = @()
        $ArgumentsArray += "\\$Computer\c$\Users\$($User_List.name[$i])\$Folder"
        $ArgumentsArray += $Global:BackUp_Path
        $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock { Copy-Item -Path $args[0] -Destination $args[1] -Force -Recurse } -Name $Folder -ArgumentList $ArgumentsArray 

        
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged -Action {
        #Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
            $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
            $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
            if(-not (Get-EventSubscriber)){
                $Profile_Sum = Get-ChildItem -Path $Global:BackUp_Path -Recurse |
                    Measure-Object -Property length -Sum |
                    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
                        $Size = try{if($Profile_Sum -lt 1048576){ $TinyByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1KB) + " KB"; $TinyByte }
                        elseif($Profile_Sum -gt 1048576 -and $Profile_Sum -lt 1073741824){ $MediumByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1MB) + " MB"; $MediumByte }
                        elseif($Profile_Sum -gt 1073741824){ $GiganticByte = "  {0:N2}" -f ($Profile_Sum / 1GB) + " GB"; $GiganticByte } } Catch {}
            
                $Begin_Time = Get-Item -Path $Global:BackUp_Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime
               
                $End_Time = Get-Date -Format G  

                Get-Job | Remove-Job 
                [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Copying Complete!`nStart Time: $Begin_Time  `nEnd Time: $End_Time `nProfile Size copied: $Size")
                       
                        }
                    } | Out-Null 
                }

" "
Write-Output -InputObject "Copying will be done in background."
Write-Output -InputObject "You will be notified when copying is done."

            } catch [System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingTransportException]{
                "Unable to connect to PC: $Computer `nError: $($Error[0].Exception.Message.Split('.')[2].Trim())!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

*I removed some information that could get me in trouble but, it's all cosmetics.(:*

**EDIT:** *I must be on crack but, everything is working now. Only changes I made was clearing the global variables (`$Global:var = $null`) before assigning it a value. Thank you all for the suggestions. Another change i made was change `Copy-Item` to `Robocopy` instead.*

Comment: "my if statement isn't analyzing the condition properly" - I count multiple `if` statements in your code, which one is affected?

Comment: Oops, sorry! Edited it . It's the condition checking if there's no more events in `Get-EventSubscriber`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using events? Have you tried adding all the jobs to an array and waiting for them to complete that way? `$jobs = @(); $jobs +=  Start-Job ... ; $jobs | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob; display messagebox`

Comment: @antonyoni, so I can have an interactive console. I can't help but think it's the global variables that are the issue. It worked fine before I changed it to global variables. Although I was getting the users folder copied over using `Get-ChildItem path | Sort LastWriteTime -Descending | Select -First 1`, the problem with this, it's inaccurate. Inaccurate in the sense of, if someone else is copying to that share, it'll get that folder instead; hence why I made them backup path global

Comment: To multithread copying many small files from a remote machine, **please** consider using `robocopy` in backup mode. You can run it directly from powershell: `robocopy $src $dst /b /mir /mt:8 /r:0 /w:0`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale, I've actually updated it on the one i'm working on at the moment.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is copy files but you want to do multiple copying tasks in parallel. Am I understanding it correctly? I would suggest using runspaces. You can create a runspacepool that manages them and at the end have a loop that checks runspace availability. If they are set as Available, close the runspace pool, show the messagebox and terminate.

Comment: Runspaces is a little out of my scope, especially tying them together using synchronized hashtable. If you'd like to show an example i'd be willing to give it a shot myself. The code is working though. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

To just answer your question:

> Why is my if statement not being read properly?

Just before you evaluate [`Get-EventSubscriber`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-eventsubscriber?view=powershell-7.1) your are cancelling your event subscription and thus deleting your event subscriber. `Get-EventSubscriber` therefore returns `$null` which evaluates to `$true`, when negated. In conclusion, the code after your `if` statement will always be executed immediately.

Commented code:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged -Action {
    $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event    # Here you cancel your event subscription
    $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
    if (-not (Get-EventSubscriber)) {      # Therefore, Get-EventSubscriber returns $null; not $null evaluates to $true
        ...
```

The relevant part in the documentation of [`Unregister-Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unregister-event?view=powershell-7.1):

> The `Unregister-Event` cmdlet cancels an event subscription that was created by using the `Register-EngineEvent`, `Register-ObjectEvent`, or `Register-WmiEvent` cmdlet.
>
> When an event subscription is canceled, the event subscriber is deleted from the session and the subscribed events are no longer added to the event queue. When you cancel a subscription to an event created by using the `New-Event` cmdlet, the new event is also deleted from the session.

Comment: Right, that's the purpose of it. The event that it's looking for is "StateChanged" produced by `Start-Job`. If you remove the global variables from the if `{}` block, it works the way it's intended to. So the purpose of that code is to exist until the condition is met. Once it is, erase itself. The if statement is supposed to evaluate nothing being left in the queue, **then** run the rest of the code to include the messagebox.

Comment: So, it *removes* itself, only after the state has changed.

Comment: To solve your problem, which is not in the scope of your question, I recommend to not use event handling at all. Just loop through your folders, as you already did, start your jobs and then just use [`Wait-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/wait-job?view=powershell-7.1) to wait until your jobs are done. Then you can execute your GUI message and so on. And to calculate the time.... just save the start time _before_ you run the for loop and store the end time after you waited for all jobs to finnish.

Comment: That defeats the purpose of the script. I'm aware I could've done that from the start, but its the nature of where I work to get this to be ran in the background completely. We have tons of profiles that have tons of data, waiting for each one individually doesn't cut it. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: There might be a misunderstanding. I do not suggest something different. Start your background jobs like you are already doing. But instead of trying to wait for every job to fire its "finished" event, you can just wait for every job by using `Wait-Job`. It is exactly the same thing, but with already existing, built-in tools. It is at least a good practice and also enhances the readability of your code.